# install pandas on rhel using yum

Tags: pandas, installation, yum, rhel

If I want to install pandas on RHEL server using the following command from the official pandas documentation [pandas installation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html) using the following command:

```
yum install python3-pandas
```

I get the following error:

```
No package python3-pandas available
Nothing to do
```

Below are the specs for my RHEL and python configuration

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release  
# Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8
$ python -V
# Python 3.6.9
$ yum install python3
# Package python3-3.6.8-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
# Nothing to do
$ python3 -V
# Python 3.6.9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I tried installing other python packages but same error. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `python3-pandas` in EPEL for RHEL 7.

However, there *is* `python-pandas` which is the Python 2 version of the same.